# Why one can say that the inner product in $\bigotimes\limits_{n=1}^{N}\mathbb{C}_n^2$ has the following form?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-states, spin-chains

In the article "Quantum theory of measurement and
macroscopic observables" of Klaus Hepp it is said that for a lattice of $N$ spin $\frac{1}{2}$ systems each in $\mathbb{C}^2$, so that the full system lies in $\bigotimes\limits_{n=1}^{N}\mathbb{C}_n^2$. Considering eigenstates in $\mathbb{C}^2$ that are $\mathbb{R}^3 \ni e\,, e\cdot \vec{\sigma}\,|\,e\,\rangle = |\,e\,\rangle$, so that if $|\,e^i\,\rangle_N=\bigotimes\limits_{n=1}^{N}|\,e^i_n\,\rangle \in \bigotimes\limits_{n=1}^{N}\mathbb{C}_n^2$ it then says that those have a scalar product of:
$$|{}_N\langle\,e^1\,|\,e^2\,\rangle_N|^2= \prod_{n=1}^{N}\frac{(1+e^1_n\cdot e^2_n)}{2}.$$

But isn't the usual inner product of a tensor product given by:
$$\langle\,\psi \otimes \phi\,|\,\varphi \otimes \xi\,\rangle = \langle\,\psi \,|\,\varphi \rangle \langle\, \phi\,|\, \xi\,\rangle$$
$$ \implies|{}_N\langle\,e^1\,|\,e^2\,\rangle_N|^2=\left|\prod_{n=1}^{N}e^1_n\cdot e^2_n\right|^2 \,\,?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're good until the last line. Note that $\langle \mathbf e |\mathbf g\rangle$ cannot simply be $\mathbf e \cdot \mathbf g$, because if $\mathbf e = \hat z$ and $\mathbf g = -\hat z$ then the corresponding vectors should be orthogonal (respectively spin up and spin down along $\hat z$) but $\mathbf e \cdot \mathbf g = -1$.

Letting $|\mathbf e\rangle = \pmatrix{a\\b}$,
$$\mathbf e \cdot \vec \sigma |\mathbf e\rangle= \pmatrix{e_z & e_x-ie_y\\e_x+ie_y&-e_z}\pmatrix{a\\b} = \pmatrix{a\\b}$$
$$\iff (e_z - 1) a + (e_x-ie_y)b = 0$$
Therefore, the normalized $+1$ eigenvector of $\mathbf e \cdot \vec \sigma$ is (up to a phase, of course) given by
$$|\mathbf e\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(1-e_z)}}\pmatrix{e_x - i e_y\\ 1-e_z}$$
You can work out the inner product between two such vectors with some brute force algebra or by being clever with vector operators; the result is indeed

$$|\langle \mathbf g|\mathbf e\rangle|^2 = \frac{1+\mathbf e \cdot \mathbf g}{2}$$